# wysihtml5: unwanted CSS synchronisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wysihtml5

I'm using [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) script. So, it transforms textarea elements to a html editor. At the moment of editor construction it copies CSS properties of the textarea element and adds it as **inline**  CSS properties to the iframe tag.

So, when editor is loaded `<iframe>` tag looks like:

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; clear: none; float: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85); outline-offset: 0px; padding: 6px 12px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: text-bottom; text-align: start; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset; border-radius: 4px; width: 330px; height: 214px;">
```

Now I want to change css properties of the editor. Because CSS is inline I can not use classes for that, instead I use .css jQuery function:

```
$(jqObject).parent().find("iframe").css({'background-color': '#000000'});
```

If I check property right after I set it, I'll get #000000 value. But there is some listener (probably to "change" event) that set CSS properties back to initial state from inline properties:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
```

My question is where is this functionality that synchronises CSS? In what objects I should look for it - Composer, Synchronizer, Editor? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Not familiar with this specific library, but I know Chrome has great debugging tools for HTML modification. On your first breakpoint, try right-clicking the iframe in the element viewer, and go to "Break On>...Attribute Modification". You might step past some other attributes being modified, but it should freeze when the style attribute is changed.

Comment: Not really a direct answer to  your question, but have you noticed that the link you gave was to an older (unsupported) version of the editor.  The new one is here: http://wysihtml.com/ and doesn't look like it uses iframes anymore.  If you can upgrade, it might help you with your problem.